# UUPS vs Beacon proxy pattern

Tags: solidity, openzeppelin, openzeppelin-contracts, proxy-contracts

I am delving into UUPS(Universal Upgradeable Proxy Standard) and Beacon proxy patterns.

I believe they serve distinct purposes, but I am unsure about the right use cases for each.

It seems that UUPS operates more independently than Beacon. However, Beacon utilizes its factory to create multiple proxy contracts with a single logic.

Could you please enlighten me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the diagram.

[image]

The `BeaconProxy` is just the first part of the `BeaconPattern`. The `BeaconProxy` itself is:

- not upgradeable
- does not store the implementation address

This is a crucial difference compared to `UUPS`. In the `BeaconPattern`, the implementation address is stored in another contract — the `IBeacon`. This approach makes possible to upgrade the implementation address for all `BeaconProxies` (for common `IBeacon`) with a single transaction. With `UUPS`, if you update the implementation, you must update every `UUPS` proxy contract.

Answer (score 1):

UUPS is used when you need only one **single** upgradable contract. For example if you think you'll need to change the logic of a contract in the future, then you can make it a UUPS.

A beacon is used when you need **multiple** upgradable contracts, all with the same logic. For example if you need to deploy a lot of tokens that follow the same logic, and you want to make them all upgradable, then you can use a Beacon proxy.
You can think of it like an upgradable version of the Clones pattern.